# ¿Para que sirven las dependencias de desarrollo en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Llevo ya tiempo trabajando con este framework, pero aun nose cual es la funcionalidad de estas "dependencias de desarrollo". Esto lo pregunto porque al subir un proyecto a produccion ejecuto el siguiente comando siempre:

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Y lo que hace es remover dichas dependencias, yo lo hago para eliminar archivos innecesarios que creo que son, pero la razon correcta a esto nose. Agregando a esta pregunta me gustaria saber ¿Cual es la diferencia entre trabajar un proyecto subido con estas dependencias y un proyecto subido al ejecutar el comando que puse?

**Update**

Como ejemplo pondre las dependencias de produccion de Laravel 5.3

```
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
}
```

Aunque a parte de estas, se instalan otras que supongo sirven para complementar las anteriores, como `sebastian`

Espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: Cuales son esas dependencias? Podrías compartir el archivo `composer.json`? Por ejemplo en este [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/composer.json), bajo la clave `"require-dev"` están los paquete que no se instalarían con `composer install --no-dev`, y cómo verás si los googleas, la mayoría son para correr tests, lo que en un ambiente de producción, no usarías.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ok lo pondre como ejemplo Laravel 5.3, aunque ya es antigua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las dependencias de desarrollo son eso mismo, dependencias que ayudan en el desarrollo pero no son necesarias para correr la aplicación.

En las dependencias que pones por ejemplo encontramos:

`phpunit/phpunit` que es un entorno para correr pruebas unitarias.

`mockery/mockery`  que nos permite simular objetos para usarlos en los test unitarios

`fzaninotto/faker` nos permite crear un gran número de valores ficticios para utilizar en nuestros test unitarios

`symfony/css-selector` y `symfony/dom-crawler` se utilizan para lectura y manipulación del dom de archivos como HTML y XML,  en los test se utiliza en algunos assert de laravel para determinar si la respuesta contiene lo que esperamos como un tag HTML o una clase CSS...

Si te fijas en que hace cada una por defecto no necesitas ninguna para correr la aplicación en producción pero si nos facilitan la vida a la hora de realizar test en el desarrollo de la aplicación, hay muchas otras dependencias que se pueden instalar para ayudarnos en la depuración y desarrollo de una aplicación. Por este motivo composer las separa en `require` y `require-dev` de forma de no tener que arrastrar a producción ciertas dependencias que sólo están para ayudarnos en la fase de desarrollo.

Comment: Entiendo, una pregunta agregando a esto. ¿Como hago para que nunca se instalen esas dependencias al hacer un `composer update`, `composer remove`, al crear un proyecto de laravel, etc. Esto lo pregunto ya que siempre tengo que colocar `composer --no-dev` cuando instalo, remuevo o actualizo

Comment: El comportamiento por defecto es que se instalen si no las quieres debes utilizar la bandera `--no-dev` o si no puedes también eliminarlas con remove dichas dependencias en caso de que no las utilices nunca. Otra opción es que empieces ha hacer tus test y les des uso y de camino aprendas poco a poco a realizar pruebas unitarias.

Comment: Lo ultimo si, pero como ya tengo proyectos en produccion queria saber ese comando